# How to return convert value of type 'Date' to 'String' in swift

Tags: swift, string, boolean, dateformatter

I want to overlap date after that return boolean.

```
func overLap(start1: String, end1: String, start2: String, end2: String) -> Bool {
    if start1 < end2 && start2 < end1 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

let start1 = "2019/02/01"
let end1 = "2019/02/20"
let start2 = "2019/02/15"
let end2 = "2019/03/02"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"

let dateFromString1 = dateFormatter.date(from: start1)
let dateFromString2 = dateFormatter.date(from: end1)
let dateFromString3 = dateFormatter.date(from: start2)
let dateFromString4 = dateFormatter.date(from: end2)

let myString = formatter.String(from: )

let result: Bool = overLap(start1: dateFromString1, end1: dateFromString2, start2: dateFromString3, end2: dateFromString4)
print(result)
```

**This is  error**: cannot convert value of type 'Date?' to expected argument type 'String'
let result: Bool = overLap(start1: dateFromString1, end1: dateFromString2, start2: dateFromString3, end2: dateFromString4)

Comment: If you convert the strings to Date objects then your function needs to take Date as parameter type for the parameters, `overLap(start1: Date, end1: Date, start2: Date, end2: Date)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a classic type mismatch error. You cannot compare apples (`Date`) and oranges (`String`).

You don't need to create `Date` instances. Compare the strings with the `numeric` option

```
func overLap(start1: String, end1: String, start2: String, end2: String) -> Bool {
    if start1.compare(end2, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending
        && start2.compare(end1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending {
        return false
    }
    return true
}

let start1 = "2019/02/01"
let end1 = "2019/02/20"
let start2 = "2019/02/15"
let end2 = "2019/03/02"

let result = overLap(start1: start1, end1: end1, start2: start2, end2: end2)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `overLap` method to,

```
func overLap(start1: Date, end1: Date, start2: Date, end2: Date) -> Bool {
    if start1.compare(end2) == .orderedAscending && start2.compare(end1) == .orderedAscending {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

In the above method, instead of using `String` as parameter types, use `Date`. Next, use `compare(_:)` to compate the `start1, end1, start2 and end2` dates.

**Usage:**

```
let start1 = "2019/02/01"
let end1 = "2019/02/20"
let start2 = "2019/02/15"
let end2 = "2019/03/02"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"

if let dateFromString1 = dateFormatter.date(from: start1),
    let dateFromString2 = dateFormatter.date(from: end1),
    let dateFromString3 = dateFormatter.date(from: start2),
    let dateFromString4 = dateFormatter.date(from: end2) {
    let result: Bool = overLap(start1: dateFromString1, end1: dateFromString2, start2: dateFromString3, end2: dateFromString4)
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: `Date` conforms to `Comparable` so the `<` operator is supported.